# Client disconnects after changing name but host does not?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-mirror

So i am new to Mirror and i made this to learn a bit,it changes name of the host normally but when i try it on a client he just disconnects,and without any errors.I have setup many debug.log statements to see where is the problem and it seems that is not even executing as a client,it just stops before it was called.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Mirror;
using TMPro;
using System;`
public class PlayerMovement : NetworkBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    float x, y;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    Animator animator;
    public TMP_InputField tmpf;
    public TMP_Text nameText;

    [SyncVar(hook = nameof(DisplayName))]
    public string _name = "00";

    void DisplayName(string oldName, string newName)
    {
        nameText.text = newName;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        if (!isLocalPlayer) return;
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        tmpf = GameObject.Find("NameIF").GetComponent<TMP_InputField>();
        //tmpf.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate { CmdChangeName(); });
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (!isLocalPlayer) return;
        x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        y = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(x * speed, y * speed);
        animator.SetFloat("horizontal", x);
        animator.SetFloat("vertical", y);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.KeypadEnter))
        {
            CmdChangeName();
        }
    }

    [Command]
    public void CmdChangeName()
    {
        _name = tmpf.text;
    }
```

How to fix this,i have client authority checked and i need to use commands if i want hooks and syncVar to work.